# SQL Server - Get a word between many /

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a certain word in a row containing many bars. As an example:

```
WORD1/WORD2/WORD3/WORD4/WORD5
```

I would need to get specifically `WORD 3` and/or `WORD 4`.
I tried to use `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` but couldn't get into a solid code for this.

(I am using Microsoft SQL Server)

Thanks,

Comment: "Specifically WORD 3 AND/OR WORD 4" is not clear on what you want to do.

Comment: If you're on MS-SQL Server 2016 or later, I highly recommend STRING_SPLIT. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @ne1410s   `string_split` does not guarantee order so it would not be appropriate in this situation.

Comment: @SMor As the function results in a selectable set of values, it may be appropriate depending on the criteria (which is unclear).

Comment: I need a code where I can get the content between two bars, independently of its position. The problem is, I have a row containing more than five bars, therefore in some way, it's impossible to get it by SUBSTRING or CHARINDEX (in an automated way, of course). The WORD3 AND/OR WORD4 would be the parts I would like to extract from the row.

Comment: What is yoir SQL Server version?

Comment: @ne1410s Thank you however my sql is below 2016

Comment: @Zhorov SQL Server 2012

Comment: Could you check this fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/de5eb/3

Comment: @esat thank you so much, it was close but not enough. Your code indeed help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a known or maximum number of positions, here is a illustration using a little XML.

**Note:** If your string is in a table, this is easy to nest within a CROSS APPLY or even as a TVF.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'WORD1/WORD2/WORD3/WORD4/WORD5'

Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@S,'/','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) as A(xDim)
```

**Returns**

```
Pos1    Pos2    Pos3    Pos4    Pos5    Pos6    Pos7    Pos8    Pos9
WORD1   WORD2   WORD3   WORD4   WORD5   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

**EDIT - If Your Data is in a Table**

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'WORD1/WORD2/WORD3/WORD4/WORD5')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(SomeCol,'/','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) as X(xDim)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Pos1    Pos2    Pos3    Pos4    Pos5    Pos6    Pos7    Pos8    Pos9
1   WORD1   WORD2   WORD3   WORD4   WORD5   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, John! I was able to split the words but only one in each row, therefore I couldn't match the final information. Seeing your code, I implemented it in my side and it's now working! Thank you again! Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a illustration using  `CROSS APPLY` this can be work only if you have the maximun section.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable  
(TaskId   int,  
   ColLine varchar(255)
  );  
GO  

INSERT INTO #MyTable 
SELECT 1, 'WORD1/WORD2/WORD3/WORD4/WORD5'
UNION
SELECT 2, 'WORD1/WORD2/WORD3/WORD4/WORD5/WORD6'
UNION
SELECT 3, 'WORD1/WORD2//WORD4/WORD5/WORD6'
UNION
SELECT 4, 'WORD1/WORD2'



SELECT TaskId, SPACE_1, WORD_1, WORD_2, WORD_3, WORD_4, WORD_5, WORD_6

FROM #MyTable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/',ColLine) AS SPACE_1) AS SPACE_1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SPACE_1 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(ColLine,0,SPACE_1) ELSE '' END AS WORD_1) AS WORD_1 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SPACE_1 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(ColLine,SPACE_1 + 1,LEN(ColLine) - SPACE_1) ELSE '' END AS RWORD_1) AS RWORD_1 

CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/',RWORD_1) AS SPACE_2) AS SPACE_2
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SPACE_2 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(RWORD_1,0,SPACE_2) ELSE '' END AS WORD_2) AS WORD_2
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SPACE_2 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(RWORD_1,SPACE_2 + 1,LEN(RWORD_1) - SPACE_2) ELSE '' END AS RWORD_2) AS RWORD_2 

CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/',RWORD_2) AS SPACE_3) AS SPACE_3
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SPACE_3 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(RWORD_2,0,SPACE_3) ELSE '' END AS WORD_3) AS WORD_3
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SPACE_3 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(RWORD_2,SPACE_3 + 1,LEN(RWORD_2) - SPACE_3) ELSE '' END AS RWORD_3) AS RWORD_3

CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/',RWORD_3) AS SPACE_4) AS SPACE_4
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SPACE_4 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(RWORD_3,0,SPACE_4) ELSE '' END AS WORD_4) AS WORD_4
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SPACE_4 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(RWORD_3,SPACE_4 + 1,LEN(RWORD_3) - SPACE_4) ELSE '' END AS RWORD_4) AS RWORD_4

CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/',RWORD_4) AS SPACE_5) AS SPACE_5
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SPACE_5 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(RWORD_4,0,SPACE_5) ELSE '' END AS WORD_5) AS WORD_5
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SPACE_5 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(RWORD_4,SPACE_5 + 1,LEN(RWORD_4) - SPACE_5) ELSE '' END AS RWORD_5) AS RWORD_5

CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('/',RWORD_5) AS SPACE_6) AS SPACE_6
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SPACE_6 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(RWORD_5,0,SPACE_6) ELSE '' END AS WORD_6) AS WORD_6
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SPACE_6 > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(RWORD_5,SPACE_6 + 1,LEN(RWORD_5) - SPACE_6) ELSE '' END AS RWORD_6) AS RWORD_6
DROP TABLE  #MyTable
```

Return result :

```
TaskId  WORD_1  WORD_2  WORD_3  WORD_4  WORD_5  WORD_6
1       WORD1   WORD2   WORD3   WORD4       
2       WORD1   WORD2   WORD3   WORD4   WORD5   
3       WORD1   WORD2           WORD4   WORD5   
4       WORD1
```

Comment: Wow that is an incredibly complicated solution.